# Email Priority with MS Exchange account

Tags: 2.2-froyo, email, exchange

I'm new to the Android world. Just got a corp phone (Moto Atrix w/2.2 froyo).
I have my MS Exchange account set up on the phone and get tons of email all hours of the night.
Most emails can wait until I get in the office in the morning, but some are VERY important and need to be read the minute they come in.
Is it possible to give certain emails a higher alert level than others?
Like say my boss emails me and I need to answer it at 3AM. Can I give my bosses email address priority 1 email alert (BING BING BING) and every other email I get level 3 priority (bing)?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If your boss really needs to talk to you at 3 am, he shouldn't try to contact you by email.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: setup a Google Gmail account, filter the important emails to be send to this Gmail account, attach the GMail account to your phone, and set up another alert when receiving an email from the Gmail account.

Comment: IIRC there are also filter which allow priority available from gmail. These could also be setup to implement different notification behavior, but I am not quite sure.